# Create nuget package with specific default value for IncludeAssets

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I have a class library that I want to publish as a nuget package. It contains some attributes necessary at compile time (for an analyzer to function correctly), but it doesn't need to be included transitively, i.e. `<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>` should be enabled on the package reference. I know that this can be achieved with `<DevelopmentDependency>true</DevelopmentDependency>`, however, that also sets `<IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>`, which isn't what I need. I need the default value for this to be `<IncludeAssets>compile; runtime</IncludeAssets>`.

How can I modify my package to have the correct default value?

Current state of the package definition:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <DevelopmentDependency>true</DevelopmentDependency>
    <!--some more values like package id, version, etc.-->
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

On install, this becomes

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="My.Package.Name" Version="1.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
```

I would like it to be

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="My.Package.Name" Version="1.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>compile; runtime</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
```

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @C.AugustoProiete I came to the conclusion that this is not possible with regular package specifications.

Comment: Thanks @stefan. That's unfortunate. It basically broke the `developmentDependency` usage for plugin scenarios (where we need the package for development, but don't ship it with the plugin)